# Android client and server socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

Is it possible to make connection with server Mac Address using Socket or Do I need IP address of the server to setup the connection from client to server using Socket

```
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
```

If I use IP address that change over the time so I don't want to use it. I want that remain same for the Android phone that seems Mac address to me.

Here both client and server is the Android Phone.

Comment: I suspect that identifying hosts by MAC address might not be the ideal way to solve your underlying problem; if you give us more context, we might be able to give you more help.

Comment: @mfrankli If it cant then any other way to do ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to connect to the same device, even as it might be getting a new IP address?

MAC address is one way to do that. Per [this blog post](http://www.flattermann.net/2011/02/android-howto-find-the-hardware-mac-address-of-a-remote-host/), you can read from `/proc/net/arp` and parse this information out, because Android is Linux-based. The `MAC address-IP address` mappings are stored in this file, and you can use the extracted IP address to do the `Socket` connect.

In general, you need an IP address to open a socket connection. Consider an analogy. Sending a packet over a socket is like sending a piece of mail to a street address. The IP address is the street address. If you don't know where your friend lives, you can't send her mail. If she moves, and doesn't tell you her new address, you can't send her more mail.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to connect to the same device, even as it might be getting a new IP address? - No I want server and client on different android phone and want to setup connection with server from client. Here I required IP address which I want to remain same

Comment: So `/proc/net/arp` can we access this file data without root ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that's an easy one to test out! (I imagine you need root.) Like I said, we could be more helpful with more context.

Comment: OK, Are you sure we can create socket connection between server and client using MAC address of the Android server phone ? Any link ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you *can't*; you need the IP address. The ARP table lets you search for a MAC address (which you know) to get the IP address (which you need).

Comment: But here IP address of the Android phone change over a time (at least 2 times in day). I want something that remain same and create a socket connection using that

Comment: see my edit. summary - to open a socket, you need an ip address.

Comment: so there is no way other than IP address to do this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51034/discussion-between-mick-and-mfrankli)